# How to set _GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=0 in Makefile

Tags: c++, makefile, cmakelists-options

In `CMakelists.txt` we can use `add_compile_definitions(_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=0)`, how can I set `_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI` in `makefile`?

Comment: `_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI = 0`?

Comment: just add `-D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=0` to your compiler command?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Alan Birtles said, I do it like this :

```
g++ $^ -std=c++14 -D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=0 $(INCLUDE) $(LIB) -o $@
```